# Instalar o pacote six no projeto python3.7

Tags: python

Estou tentando instalar [esse](https://github.com/Lu-Yi-Hsun/iqoptionapi) projeto no meu computador, mas não estou conseguindo

Já instalei o python3.7 e  quando executo comando `sudo python3.7 setup.py install`, eu tenho no final o seguinte resultado

`error: six 1.11.0 is installed but six~=1.12 is required by {'astroid'}`

Já tentei usar isso

`sudo python3 -m pip install six`

e assim

`pip install six`

Ele diz que a versão que eu tenho instalada é a 1.15.0

Eu estava tentando [esse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbgNmwL4xZA) tutorial aqui, mas não sai do primeiro vídeo

pip install six

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar o

```
pip install six==1.12.0
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

se não funcionar(somente se não funcionar) tente isso

```
pip install -U six
pip install astroid
```

Comment: Mas ele nao vai direto pra versão python2.7?

Comment: tente mesmo assim

Comment: ai depois vc tenta instalar normalmente

Comment: Blz. Obrigado!!